# Command line way to change time and timezone in vista/2008

Tags: windows, windows-vista, command-line-interface

Is there a way to to change time and timezone in vista/2008 per command line?

Answer (score 2):

This looks promising http://www.siao2.com/2006/05/30/610505.aspx

```
control.exe intl.cpl,,/f:"c:\Unattend.xml"
```